# firebase query not updating immediately

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database reference that stores all the supervisor details. I am querying the database to return only the supervisors that the status is "Not Filled", because each supervisor has a capacity of student that he can supervise. Once the number of student assigned to the supervisor equals the carrying capacity of that supervisor, the supervisor's status automatically change to "Filled". This is working correctly.

The problem I'm having is that the thing is not updating immediately. When all the supervisors are filled, the program continue to execute except I kill the app and rerun it. I don't need to be killing the app and relaunch it every time that I want to assign a supervisor to a student, because student may decide to use one mobile phone for the registration and they don't need to be launching the app every time of registration.

```
private String getSupervisors() {

    Query databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Supervisors").orderByChild("status").equalTo("Not Filled");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                List<String> supervisorsList =new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    supervisorsList.add(dataSnapshot.child("sid").getValue().toString());
                }

                Log.d("Main", "The list contains " + supervisorsList);
                supervisorChose = supervisorsList.get(new Random().nextInt(supervisorsList.size()));
                Log.d("Main", "The selected supervisor is " + supervisorChose);
                Log.d("Main", "The total supervisor in the system is " + supervisorsList.size());
            }else {
                Log.d("Main","There is no supervisor in the list");
                showMessage("Error","All supervisors are filled, contact the admin for more details");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(StudentRegistrationActivity.this, "Error From the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return supervisorChose;
}

private void retrieveSupervisorInfo(String registrationNumber, String profileImage, String name) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.child("Supervisors").child(getSupervisors()).exists()) {
                Supervisor supervisor = snapshot.child("Supervisors").child(supervisorKey).getValue(Supervisor.class);
                String supervisorStatus = "";
                String supervisorName = supervisor.getName();
                String supervisorUniqueKey = supervisor.getSid();
                int carryingCapacity = supervisor.getCapacity();
                int numberAssigned = supervisor.getNumberAssigned();

                registerStudent(registrationNumber, profileImage, name, supervisorName, supervisorUniqueKey);
                numberAssigned += 1;

                if (numberAssigned >= carryingCapacity) {
                    supervisorStatus = "Filled";
                } else {
                    supervisorStatus = "Not Filled";
                }
                Log.d("Main", "The selected supervisor is " + supervisorName);
                Log.d("Main", "The supervisorKey is " + supervisorUniqueKey);
                Log.d("Main", "The carrying capacity of the supervisor is " + carryingCapacity);
                Log.d("Main", "The total number of students assigned to this supervisor is " + numberAssigned);
                Log.d("Main", "The status of this supervisor is " + supervisorStatus);

                updateSupervisorInfo(supervisorKey, supervisorStatus, numberAssigned);
            } else {
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("Main", "There is no such supervisor");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(StudentRegistrationActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: None of the code you shared seems to deal with displaying of he data as far as I can see. Are you showing this data in a `ListView`/`RecyclerView` somewhere? If so, can you show how?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: I am not displaying the info, what I meant is that all the supervisors in the database were filled but the app keeps accepting student's registration in which it supposed not to be so. The registration shouldn't be successful immediately all the supervisors is filled. It supposed to show an error message that there is no more available supervisor. The thing only works if and only if I kill the app and relaunch it after the last student's registration, i.e after the last available slot was assigned to student so I was suspecting that maybe the app is  not being updated on time @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: You should be able to pretty quickly determine that in a debugger. Set a breakpoint on `if (snapshot.exists()) {` and run the code in a debugger. Does the breakpoint hit when the last supervisor is claimed? If so, step through the code and check what goes wrong there.